# Filter or scope relations shown in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Is it possible in a nested form to filter/scope elements shown?

example :

```
class User
  has_many :user_shop_datas
end
```

view :

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.fields_for :user_shop_datas
  .... 


class UserShopData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validate :user, uniqueness:{scope: :shop_id}
  belongs_to :shop
  scope :from_shop, -> (shop) { where(shop_id: shop) }
end
```

I want to filter the nested form of the user with a `where shop: current_shop`, which is dynamic, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a scope in your `UserShopData` (I expect the model for `:user_shop_datas` is `UserShopData`

**user_shop_data.rb**

```
class UserShopData < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :from_shop_id, -> (shop_id) { where(shop_id: shop_id) }
end
```

So you query in the view will be:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  fields_for @user.user_shop_datas.from_shop_id(current_shop.id)
  ....
```

Comment: It does not seems to like that : `undefined method \`model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Comment: Hmm could you update how you define the model of `user_shop_datas`

Comment: Could you give me the error message with stacktrace?